# Работа с указателями в C++

Tags: c++, указатели, синтаксис

Допустим, я объявляю переменную

```
int a = 5;
```

Чем будут отличаться два варианта объявления указателя:

```
int *p;
*p = &a;
```

и

```
int *p;
p = &a;
```

если в обоих случаях

```
cout<< *p;
```

выдает одинаковый результат 5?

Comment: Хотя бы тем, что `*p = &a;` - некорректный С++ код, который даже не скомпилируется. Посему никакого "одинакового результата в обоих случаях" тут нет и быть не может - вы что-то выдумываете.

Comment: @AnT Не понимаю почему это не должно скомпилироватся. В худшем случае, если sizeof(int) меньше sizeof(pointer) будет предупреждение о возможном усекании значения. Касательно одинакового результата - теоретически подобное возможно, хотя тут скорее всего автор вопроса допустил ошибку.

Comment: Ok, это работает в С. В С++ заработает только с доп. флагами при компиляции.

Comment: @Dorin Botan: Ни язык С, ни язык С++ не разрешают неявного преобразования значения типа "указатель" к целому типу. Никакие `sizeof` тут ни при чем. В языках С и С++ нет такого понятия, как "доп. флаги". Такой код является ошибочным и в С, и в С++. Все остальное - либо глюки вашего компилятора, либо неправильная интерпретация компиляторной диагностики вами лично.

Comment: @AnT: Неявное преобразование типа является нежелательным но не ошибочным (как минимум в С), значит поводов не компилировать подобную программу нет. sizeof как раз играет ключевую роль, так как от размера типов на отдельной архитектуре зависит - вызовет ли преобразование реальные проблемы или компилятор будет жаловатся без повода.

Comment: @AnT: Нет чёткого понятия С/С++, есть несколько стандартов которые в разной степени реализованы разными компиляторами. Разработчики компиляторов вольны трактовать все `implementation defined` и `undefined behavior` стандартов C/С++ так как сами считают нужным. Обсуждение конверсии int -> pointer -> int в C/C++ в отрыве от компиляторов не имеет смысла, так как согласно [ISO/IEC 9899:2011](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT36-C.+Converting+a+pointer+to+integer+or+integer+to+pointer), это самый что ни на есть `implementation defined bahaviour`.

Comment: @Dorin Botan: В каждый момент оба языка имеют единственные стандарты, а не "несколько стандартов". И именно в этом вопросе эти стандарты совершенно однозначны (и, кстати, всегда были однозначны). Неявное преобразование указателей в целые строго и однозначно запрещено и в С, и в С++. Никакого implementation-defined behavior тут нет. Откуда вы это взяли - не ясно.

Comment: @AnT: §6.3.2.3 - [ISO/IEC 9899:2011] Programming Languages—C, 3rd ed.

Цитата: `An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.
Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type.`

Comment: @AnT: Доступа к стандарту С++ у меня нет, но `The C++ Programming Language 3rd ed.` Страуструпа в §6.2 абсолюно ничего не говорит про каст pointer -> integer, а значит, скорее всего всё аналогично Си.

Comment: @AnT: Касательно нескольких станартов - Весь embedded до сих пор придерживается ANSI-C, C99 до сих пор целиком не поддерживается многими компиляторами (попробуйте скомпилировать C99 код последним GCC без флагов) а к С11 компиляторы даже ввели отдельный макрос `__STDC_VERSION__` что бы улучшить переносимость между разными компиляторами программ написанных с использованием разных стандартов. Это именно **несколько** стандартов которые существуют параллельно в один момент.

Comment: @Dorin Botan: Опять двадцать пять. 6.3.2.3 описывает поведение **явного** преобразования. Никакого разрешения на неявное преобразования в 6.3.2.3 нет и никогда не было. Более того, специально для вас в текст было добавлено 6.5.4/3 "Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the constraints of
6.5.16.1, **shall be specified by means of an explicit cast**." Что там использует embedded никому не интересно и не имеет никакого значения. В наше время это говорит это лишь о низком уровне компетенции embedded-разработчиков.

Comment: Рассказы про то, что кто-то где-то использует древние стандарты языка, в данном контексте совершенно не уместны, ибо рассматриваемое преобразование не поддерживается ни в одном из этих стандартов. (Как я уже говорил выше, неявное преобразование из указателя в целое было запрещено в С и С++ **всегда**.) Что вы хотите сказать вашими рассказами про GCC и "флаги" не ясно тоже - всем прекрасно известно, что для того, чтобы перевести этот компилятор в режим С или С++ его необходимо тщательно конфигурировать. Что делает GCC "без флагов" никому не интересно и к данной теме никак не относится.

Answer (score 2):

```
int *p;
*p = &a;
```

Отличие будет в том, что этот вариант не скомпилируется, так как вы пытаетесь записать в невыделенную память для целочисленного значения адрес переменной `a`

Comment: Скомпилируется - если в режиме C и плевать на предупреждения :)

Comment: Думаю, вы лучше знаете, но судя по меткам вопрос о С++. Ни LLVM ни GCC такой код не хотят есть с однозначным `invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'`

Comment: @Harry: Термин "скомпилируется" означает: пройдет компиляцию без требуемых стандартом языка диагностических сообщений. Поэтому нет, в С этот код НЕ скомпилируется. Никакой разницы между С и С++ в этом отношении нет.

Comment: @Артём Оконечников: Вы совершенно правы. Код строго ошибочен и в С и в С++.

Answer (score 2):

**Объявления** у вас одинаковы -

```
int *p;
```

А вот **присваивания** - разные...

```
*p = &a;
```

Присваивание значению по адресу `p` значения адреса переменной `a`, что
1. в режиме C++ без дополнительного преобразования является ошибкой и не компилируемо;
2. если бы даже было компилируемо, то в `cout << *p` вывести 5 могло только по очень невероятной случайности - и то вряд ли: ну не используются обычно такие адреса (а в `*p` в этом случае находится именно *адрес* `a`) для реальных переменных...;
3. записывает неопределенную (ибо переменная `p` не инициализирована) область памяти, что является UB, могущим в хорошем случае аварийно тормознуть программу.

Второе присваивание

```
p = &a;
```

помещает в переменную `p` адрес `a`, так что `*p` представляет собой по сути псевдоним `a`, и выводимое в этом случае значение `cout << *p` действительно является значением переменной `a`.